My Svelte button component is disappearing and not placed in the correct place when implementing into my page
I am making a project with SvelteKit and I made a button component in the lib folder. I imported it into my main +page.svelte file and referenced it under my title. The content of the whole page then loads for a split second and disappears. This is the code of the page:
<script>
    import Button from '$lib/Button.svelte'
   
    const handleClick = () =>
    {
        console.log("Clicked")
    }
</script>

<head>
    <title>E-client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">

        <h1 >Welcome to Email Cient!</h1>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Log in to access email</h3>
        <Button on:click={handleClick}>Log In</Button>
    </div>
</body>

Button.svelte:
<button on:click>
    <slot/>
</button>

I tried nesting the button in a different div, but that didn't give any different results. I have tried to set a variable like buttonLoaded, and only rendering the button when the variable is true using {#if} statement. This allowed the whole page to load except for the actual button, and the button was not visible in the dev tools. I am kind of new to Sveltekit so I am not sure what else to do or try.
There is an error that appears:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation

    in +layout.svelte
    in root.svelte

But I have searched around and haven't found a solution.
Here is my +layout.svelte code:
<script>
    import '../styles/global.css';
</script>

<header>
    <div class="navBar">
        <nav>
            <ul class="navLinks">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="lgButton"><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <slot />
</main>

Package.json:
{
    "name": "email-frontend",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^4.0.0",
        "svelte": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^5.0.3"
    }
}


Looks like some kind of hydration issue. Probably hard to answer as is, see if you can get more information about where exactly the error occurs and why. The stack trace might link to  particular pieces of code.

How would I get more information on the error?

Inspect it in the browser dev tools.

E.g. for Chrome, see this reference page for general debugging information. See this question about error stack traces.

remove body tag as it isn't allowed, use enclose the content inside body in another div tag.
